# How to split a map in catchment areas (polygons gathering the closest points of specific points)

Tags: maps, polygon

I want to create an algorithm to determine the catchment areas of recycling bins in a city.

The idea : I have several points on a map, and I want to trace the polygons of their catchment areas. I consider that the catchment area is the zone where this recycling bin is the closest one.

I found that the edges of these polygons are parts of the line segment bisectors between 2 recycling bins.

But I haven't found yet how to select mathematically which intersections of line segment bisectors are the vertexes of the polygons of catchment areas.
(all the intersections of line segment bisectors aren't interesting)

Here is a picture of what I want to do (crosses are recycling bins and lines are the edges that demarcate catchment areas).

Any idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer : with the Voronoi diagram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)